# setOnCheckedChangeListener not firing

Tags: android

In my fragment I have the following code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Routes_Checkbox_Pickup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Routes_EditText_AlarmPickup.setEnabled(isChecked);
                Routes_Spinner_Pickup_Routes.setEnabled(isChecked);
                Routes_Spinner_Pickup_TrackingLocations.setEnabled(isChecked);
            if(isChecked==true)
                Routes_EditText_AlarmPickup.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    Routes_Checkbox_Drop.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Routes_EditText_AlarmDrop.setEnabled(isChecked);
            Routes_Spinner_Drop_Routes.setEnabled(isChecked);
            Routes_Spinner_Drop_TrackingLocations.setEnabled(isChecked);
            if(isChecked==true)
                Routes_EditText_AlarmDrop.requestFocus();

        }
    });
}
```

On a buttons click I have the following code:

```
Routes_Checkbox_Pickup.setChecked(false);
```

However the above code does not fire the events set above. What's wrong ?

**EDIT**

Full code:

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.routes_fragment, container, false);

        Routes_Checkbox_Pickup = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.Routes_Checkbox_Pickup);
        Routes_Spinner_Pickup_Routes = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.Routes_Spinner_Pickup_Routes);
        Routes_TextInputLayout_AlarmPickup = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.Routes_TextInputLayout_AlarmPickup);
        Routes_EditText_AlarmPickup = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Routes_EditText_AlarmPickup);
        Routes_Spinner_Pickup_TrackingLocations = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.Routes_Spinner_Pickup_TrackingLocations);

        Routes_Checkbox_Drop = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.Routes_Checkbox_Drop);
        Routes_Spinner_Drop_Routes = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.Routes_Spinner_Drop_Routes);
        Routes_TextInputLayout_AlarmDrop = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.Routes_TextInputLayout_AlarmDrop);
        Routes_EditText_AlarmDrop = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Routes_EditText_AlarmDrop);
        Routes_Spinner_Drop_TrackingLocations = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.Routes_Spinner_Drop_TrackingLocations);

        Routes_Button_Save = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Routes_Button_Save);
        Routes_Button_Save.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_enabled);

        Routes_EditText_AlarmPickup.setSingleLine(true);
        Routes_EditText_AlarmDrop.setSingleLine(true);

        Routes_Checkbox_Pickup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    Routes_EditText_AlarmPickup.setEnabled(isChecked);
                    Routes_Spinner_Pickup_Routes.setEnabled(isChecked);
                    Routes_Spinner_Pickup_TrackingLocations.setEnabled(isChecked);
                if(isChecked==true)
                    Routes_EditText_AlarmPickup.requestFocus();
            }
        });
        Routes_Checkbox_Drop.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Routes_EditText_AlarmDrop.setEnabled(isChecked);
                Routes_Spinner_Drop_Routes.setEnabled(isChecked);
                Routes_Spinner_Drop_TrackingLocations.setEnabled(isChecked);
                if(isChecked==true)
                    Routes_EditText_AlarmDrop.requestFocus();

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you show the whole code of your fragment?

Comment: Where are you initializing `Routes_Checkbox_Pickup`, since I dont see any view being inflated in onCreateView, i feel your code is much complex than expected. So i guess full code can help better

Comment: I have posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the viewHolder is not there to update the UI

**before onCreateView()**  add

```
ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
```

then **change**

```
Routes_Checkbox_Pickup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                holder.Routes_EditText_AlarmPickup.setEnabled(isChecked);
                holder.Routes_Spinner_Pickup_Routes.setEnabled(isChecked);
                holder.Routes_Spinner_Pickup_TrackingLocations.setEnabled(isChecked);
            if(isChecked==true)
                holder.Routes_EditText_AlarmPickup.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    Routes_Checkbox_Drop.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 

CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                holder.Routes_EditText_AlarmDrop.setEnabled(isChecked);
                holder.Routes_Spinner_Drop_Routes.setEnabled(isChecked);


holder.Routes_Spinner_Drop_TrackingLocations.setEnabled(isChecked);
                if(isChecked==true)
                    holder.Routes_EditText_AlarmDrop.requestFocus();
            }
        });
```

**also use holder to initize the button views in onCreateView()**

Comment: RecyclerView.ViewHolder cant be initialized. holder = RecyclerView.ViewHolder new RecyclerView.ViewHolder();

Comment: can you please paste you total class code here I will try and compile and hopefully come up with a solution :)

Comment: I have posted the code, can you please help me out.